# How do I express "for all" and "there exists" as prdicates on lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am writing a function over two lists and a relation and I want to express a particular predicate in Haskell. The example below is using integer lists and equality but I will generalize it to arbitrary binary relations over lists. I would appreciate a hint for how to do this for the particular example here before I generalize it.

If I have the following:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [3,4,5,6]
```

And I want to have a predicate as follows:

```
for all elements e2 in l2, there exists an element e1 in l1 such that (e1 = e2)
```

So more generally, it would be

```
for all elements e2 in l2, there exists an element e1 in l1 such that R (e1 e2)
```

Where R is some binary relation.

How would I write this predicate in Haskell?

Comment: You might be interested in the [any](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:any) and [all](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:all) functions.

Comment: This question is ambiguous. It's unclear what happens if there are duplicates in one of the lists.

Comment: Are you asking for a function that returns the value of the predicate? Or some kind of ability to witness eg. at the type-level that the predicate holds?

Comment: @RobinZigmond thank you!! figured it out. It's and [any (\x -> (m1 == x)) l2 | m1 <- l1].

Comment: @Redu sorry, not sure what you mean? Duplicates don't change anything.

Comment: @Lana If you figured it out, then maybe could you post that as an answer to your own question? Right now this question is listed as being unanswered.

Comment: @bradrn Sure. I figured someone could have a better way to do this without using lists and by using all as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write:

> for all elements e2 in l2, there exists an element e1 in l1 such that R (e1 e2) [sic]

I write:

```
-- for all elements e2 in l2,
all (\e2 -> ...) l2
-- there exists an element e1 in l1
any (\e1 -> ...) l1
-- such that R e1 e2
r e1 e2
```

All together now:

```
all (\e2 -> any (\e1 -> r e1 e2) l1) l2
```

Without loss of generality we can swap the argument order to `r`, and then you could also write it this way, which is slightly shorter:

```
all (\e2 -> any (r e2) l1) l2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

> ```
>  and [any (\x -> (m1 == x)) l2 | m1 <- l1]
> ```

Not sure that this is the best way to write it since it also uses lists, but it works.

Comment: Instead of `any` you can use `or`.